# null pointer exception in page please help

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting this error when I press the save2 command button in the plus sign
Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!submitLead}' in page permissionsinspector: Class.myEmployeeController3.submitLead: line 20, column 1

An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.
Here is my visaulforce page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="myEmployeeController3">
    <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

        <style>
            p { font-weight: bold; }
            p {font-size: 15px;}
            h1,h2 {display:block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;}
            h1 {font-size: 20px;}
            h2 {font-size: 16px;}
            #inputSection {text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;}

        </style>
        <script>
        function switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2) 
        {
            var el = document.getElementById(obj);                                       
            if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                el.style.display = '';
            }
            var e2 = document.getElementById(obj1);                                       
            if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
                e2.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e2.style.display = '';
            }
            var e3 = document.getElementById(obj2);                                       
            if ( e2.style.display != 'none' ) {
                e3.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e3.style.display = '';
            }

        }
        </script>
        <apex:form >
            <h1>Permissions Inspector</h1>
            <h2>Enter Object API Name</h2>

            <div id="inputSection">
                <apex:inputText value="{!SObjectName}"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!actionSupMethod}" reRender="test2" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
            <apex:actionfunction action="{!submitLead}" name="myFunction" reRender="PBS1">
                <apex:param name="recordId" value="" assignTo="{!recordId}"/>
            </apex:actionfunction>
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="test2" value="{!objectout}" var="cus" >
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">                                        
                            THE RESULTS ARE                                                                             
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="plusimage">
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Plus_Image}" onclick="switchMenu
                                                                               ('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.minusimage}','{!$Component.plusimage}')" title="Expand"/> 
                       </apex:outputpanel>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="minusimage" style="display:none;">
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Minus_Image}"
                                        onclick="switchMenu('{!$Component.inlinetablesec}','{!$Component.plusimage}','{!$Component.minusimage}')" title="Collapse"/>
                        </apex:outputpanel>

                        <apex:outputpanel id="inlinetablesec" style="display:none;">
                            <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNum"/>
                            <apex:repeat var="count" value="{!cus.Parent.Profile.Name}">
                                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
                                <apex:commandButton value="Save2" onclick="myFunction('{!cus.ParentId}'); return false;"/>
                                </apex:repeat> 
                            <apex:outputText rendered="{!rowNum=0}">  Element Set Null </apex:outputText>

                            <apex:pageblocktable value="{!dataMap}" var="tm" rendered="{!rowNum>0}" id="PBS1">
                                <apex:column headerValue="Field names" value="{!dataMap[tm].Field}"/>
                            </apex:pageblocktable>
                        </apex:outputpanel>     
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Object" value="{!cus.SObjectType}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Read" value="{!cus.PermissionsRead}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Parent ID" value="{!cus.ParentId}"/> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Edit" value="{!cus.PermissionsEdit}"/>p
                    <apex:column headerValue="Delete" value="{!cus.PermissionsDelete}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="ViewAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsViewAllRecords}"/> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="ModifyAll" value="{!cus.PermissionsModifyAllRecords}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            <!-- <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters">
<apex:pageBlockSection id="PBS1">
Passed parameter in Form: {!recordId} <br/>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable id="test3" value="{!fieldPerms}" var="cus1" >
<apex:column headerValue="Field names" value="{!cus1.Field}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>-->
        </apex:form>

    </apex:page>
```

Here's the controller

```
public with sharing class myEmployeeController3 {
    public String SObjectName{get;set;}
    public List<ObjectPermissions> objectout{get;set;}
    public List<FieldPermissions> fieldPerms{get;set;}
    public String recordId{get; set;}

    public Map<ObjectPermissions,List<FieldPermissions>> dataMap{get; set;}
     Map<Id,ObjectPermissions> objMap = new Map<Id,ObjectPermissions>();

    public PageReference submitLead() {
        fieldPerms = [SELECT  Field, ParentId FROM FieldPermissions
                      WHERE  ParentId=:recordId AND SObjectType =:SObjectName 
                      ORDER BY Field DESC];

        if(fieldPerms != null)
        {   
            //try{
            for(FieldPermissions fp :fieldPerms)
            {
                if(!dataMap.containsKey(objMap.get(fp.ParentId)))
                {
                    dataMap.put(objMap.get(fp.ParentId),new List<FieldPermissions>());
                    dataMap.get(objMap.get(fp.ParentId)).add(fp);
                }
                else
                {
                    dataMap.get(objMap.get(fp.ParentId)).add(fp);
                }
            }
        }
        //catch (System.NullPointerException e) {

        //}
           //}  
        return null;
   }
    public myEmployeeController3(){
        recordId= '';
    }
    Public void actionSupMethod(){
        objectout =  [SELECT ParentId, Parent.Profile.Name, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsDelete,
                      PermissionsViewAllRecords,PermissionsModifyAllRecords
                      FROM ObjectPermissions 
                      WHERE SObjectType = :SObjectName AND (PermissionsRead = true OR PermissionsCreate = true 
                                                            OR PermissionsEdit = true OR PermissionsDelete = true 
                                                            OR PermissionsViewAllRecords = true OR PermissionsModifyAllRecords = true)
                      ORDER BY Parent.IsOwnedByProfile ASC];

        if(objectout != null)
        {
            for(ObjectPermissions op :objectout)
            {
                objMap.put(op.ParentId,op);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It appears one of your maps is `==` null. Have you confirmed these maps are populated prior to the `submitLead` method call? My first guess would be `dataMap` since `objMap` is initialized as an empty map (would not throw a null-pointer exception).

Comment: N.B. `fieldPerms` will never be null - if no records found, it will be an empty list - the if test is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataMap` variable is never instantiated. Before your loop, instantiate it as empty. You should also use the `ParentId` as your map key. One of my colleagues once wrote a generic utility called `GroupBy` that performs this sort of functionality. Might be worth investing some time into. It's pretty intuitive to build out.

```
dataMap = new Map<Id, List< FieldPermissions>>(); // MISSING
for(FieldPermissions fp :fieldPerms)
{
     if (!dataMap.containsKey(fp.ParentId))
        dataMap.put(fp.ParentId, new List< FieldPermissions>());
    dataMap.get(fp.ParentId).add(fp);
}
```

---

If you want to build out this utility method specifically, it would look like:

```
public class GroupBy
{
    public Map<Id, List<SObject>> ids(SObjectField lookup, List<SObject> records)
    {
        Map<Id, List<SObject>> grouped = new Map<Id, List<SObject>>();
        for (SObject record : records)
        {
            Id reference = (Id)record.get(lookup);
            if (!grouped.containsKey(reference))
                grouped.put(reference, new List<SObject>());
            grouped.get(reference).add(record);
        }
        return grouped;
    }
}
```

If you implement the above, you can simply assign the method result directly to `dataMap`.

```
dataMap = GroupBy.ids(FieldPermissions.ParentId, fieldPerms)
```